# Compilation Error with small script

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I'm trying to write a cls in Excel 2007, here's the code:

```
Dim JiraService As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set JiraService = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

JiraService.Open "GET", "URL", False
JiraService.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
JiraService.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
JiraService.Send

sRestResponse = JiraService.ResponseText

MsgBox sRestResponse
```

I'm getting a compilation error, indicating that Set appears to be invalid.

[image]

It basically says that the external procedure is not valid.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: How are you calling this code? Hope from a procedure? Or have you pasted this code in a class module directly?

Comment: I put in a class module directly.

Comment: Ah! I thought so... one moment.

Comment: Refresh the page to see FOLLOWUP in my answer below.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the appropriate reference I guess. Click on Tools~~>References in VBA

Add a project references to;

- Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1
- Microsoft XML, v6.0

Also in this line

```
JiraService.Open "GET", "URL", False
```

If `URL` is the variable which holds the actual URL then `"URL"` will be considered as a string and not a variable since it is between quotes. I guess you are trying this?

```
JiraService.Open "GET", URL, False
```

**FOLLOWUP (From Comments)**

The problem is that you have pasted the above code in a class module. You are suppose to paste the code in a module and call it in a sub. See this example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim JiraService As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set JiraService = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    JiraService.Open "GET", URL, False
    JiraService.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    JiraService.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    JiraService.Send

    sRestResponse = JiraService.ResponseText

    MsgBox sRestResponse
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Hello and thanks for your response. 
I do have the project references that you mentioned and also, the string URL I put there is just a placeholder, there's an actual URL there... So I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: I got the compile error when I didn't have the references. Can you post the screenshot of the Error message?

Comment: Just posted it, it basically says that the "external procedure is not valid".